# What exactly is this., and when do I have to use it?

Tags: java, this

I'm a beginner to coding and I recently learned about `this` and `toString()`. I'm not exactly sure what `this` is and what it does. Can someone explain it in simple words?? Also, when do I have to use it and when do I not?

One more question, why don't we have to use `this` in the `toString()` method if we already used it in a `constructor`?

Thank you so much

Comment: This is a question about what programming language?

Comment: It's about Java

Comment: @Alex Nam you should definitely have a structured book or course to learn the syntax of language. For your question I found a relevant info: https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_this.asp

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Here's another tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html.  *"Can someone explain it in simple words?"* - It does.

Answer (score 1):

This is to refer to the current object. This is in contrast to "super" which refers to the current objects parent.

Usually "this" is used to distinguish instance variables from parameters. For example:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;

   public Person(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is used to call Current Object/Current method and `toString` is used to convert any datatype into `String`. Like `int` into String. This is a keyword in java and `toString` is a predefined method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent any object as a string, toString() method comes into existence.

The toString() method returns the string representation of the object. So you can print and see the value.

If you print any object, java compiler internally invokes the toString() method on the object. So overriding the toString() method, returns the desired output, it can be the state of an object etc. depends on your implementation.

https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method